# Service create every time - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to create service only 1 time.

My service is injected into 2 components, and I set the value to true.
The problem is, the service is created always when I open the view with him and my value is default to false again.
How to make it singleton ?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalStateService {

  constructor() {
    console.log('GlobalState created');
  }

  myValue = false;
}
```

and I use it this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  model: any = {};
  permission: any;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService,
              private alertifyService: AlertifyService,
              private globalState: GlobalStateService) {
  }
```

module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NavComponent} from './nav/nav.component';
import {AuthService} from './_services/auth.service';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/register.component';
import {AlertifyService} from './_services/alertify.service';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { GlobalStateService } from './_services/global-state.service';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { changeTabReducer } from './reducers/tab.reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    BooksComponent,
    UsersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AlertifyService,
    GlobalStateService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: If the dependency injection is properly implemented, it should only inject a single instance of your service to your components. If that is not happening, it's probably due to wrong implementation. Can you include the code of the modules and components using your service?

Comment: I added, this is good ? or something more ?

Comment: Can you add the whole nav component(as in where the service is used) also the second component where the service is used.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make a service a singleton in Angular:

1. Declare that the service should be provided in the application root.
2. Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only
   imported by the AppModule.

From the docs, the [**`documentation`**](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)? You need to specify in the @Injectable decorator on the service that it should be provided in the 'root'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GlobalStateService {
}
```

Which looks good based on the code, however **NOTE :** Decorate it with `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` and **`do not provide it in any providers array.`**

Comment: and inject him to every services via constructor like I did ? well it not works

Comment: check now, I added

Comment: remove the GlobalStateService  under providers, which should work as i mentioned in the comment

Comment: not works without it, i added this now but not works also

Comment: the service is created every time new

Comment: can you provide what exactly your service code looks like? the one you provided wont even compile

Comment: I added, the value was incorrect but now this can be compiled

Comment: this service has only 1 value and this is whole service